# null Value from request header is breaking a python code

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, request, null

I have a post API where client need to pass either of 2 possible parameters. When I am doing a check for if not None value is present it is failing because for some weird reasons I get null value for each missing header. Here is the sample code.

```
if isinstance(event.get('headers'), str):
            headers_json = json.loads(event.get('headers'))
            if 'Id' in headers_json:
                request_payload['Id'] = headers_json.get('Id')
else:
    if 'Id' in event.get('headers'):
                request_payload['Id'] = event.get('headers').get('Id')

if("Id" in request_payload and request_payload["Id"] is not None and request_payload["Id"].strip() != "" and request_payload["Id"].strip().lower() != "null" and request_payload["Id"].strip().lower() != 'null'):
        opt_headers.append("Id")
    else:
        opt_headers.append("custId")
```

It never goes into the else part, when customer only sends "custID" without "ID". When I tried to print the request_payload, it shows below values in logs.

```
"Id": null,
"custId": "abc123"
```

When I print input request headers, it does not have "Id" in headers, it only has "custId". Below is the print output of input request.

```
{
"level": "INFO",
"location": "handler:22",
"message": {
    "text": "Event received",
    "details": {
        "requestContext": {
            "elb": {
                "targetGroupArn": "abc123"
            }
        },
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "path": "abc123/def345",
        "queryStringParameters": {},
        "headers": {
            "accept": "application/json;v=1",
            "custId": "abc123"
        }
      }
    }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in Advance.!!